# JSFL fl.saveDocumentAs();

Tags: flash, extending, jsfl

I am writing a JSFL script that resizes flas and saves various versions, with appened names.

I can get a "Save As" prompt to pop up using  fl.saveDocumentAs();

But I can't seem to get flash to generate a new name for the FLA.

I just want to save "document.fla" as "document_foo.fla" ,(and later "document_qux.fla"), preferably without interrupting the script with a "save as" prompt.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to achieve that without prompting. You can gather the desired file name either by asking the user or reading it from an array or whatnot but saveDocumentAs will always ask you a new file name which makes this whole point useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks, just using fl.saveDocument() works. I used this to rename it and switch Flash's focus to the new version:

```
var docURI= fl.documents[0].pathURI;// get name&location of current document
var appendName = "_appended.fla";
docURI=docURI.replace(".fla",appendName);//create appended name for new version
//(do stuff to my fla)
fl.saveDocument(fl.documents[0] ,docURI);//save as new doc name
fl.openDocument(docURI);//open this newly saved document
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use fl.saveDocumentAs().

> If the file has never been saved or **has not been modified** since the
>   last time it was saved, the file isn’t saved and false is returned. To
>   allow an unsaved or unmodified file to be saved, use
>   fl.saveDocumentAs().

Read - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7d12.html

Just use fl.saveDocument after each modification.